# Getting the error messages from HttpErrorResponse in an Angular application

Tags: angular

I have an Angular application which calls a rest api that can return an error similar to this image.

[image]

How do I parse this in my API call to extract the error message(s)?

I'm using the following code:

```
this.authService.login(this.userLogin)
    .pipe(first())
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            this.router.navigate([this.returnUrl]);
        },
        error => {
          console.log(error)
          this.alertService.validationError(error.error);
            this.isRequesting = false;
        });
```

But error.error gives me an array where I don't know what the key may be - in the image it's login_failure but it could be anything and I don't know how to parse this.

Comment: have you tried `error._body`?

Comment: I didn't know that was a thing ...?  Just tried it and got undefined

Comment: anyways I'm not able to see `login_failure` in your error message

Comment: @RobbieMills It depends on the server what key will be used for error(s). You can check out the API docs for this or just take first error and display it wherever you like

Comment: Sorry I updated the image to show the exact error

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this small snippet to extract the first error:

```
error.error[Object.keys(error.error)[0]];
```

The `Object.keys(error.error)` extracts the keys of the object as an array and then you can access the first key like you normally would in an array.

Comment: Thats perfect - secondly, how can I get the key "login_failure" in this example?

Comment: `Object.keys(error.error)[0]` this gets you the key.